# What rules are used in international events

Tags: go, tournament

What rules are used during international events like the recent [Samsung Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Cup)?

Answer (score 5):

There is no standardized international ruleset in Go.  Generally, a tournament will use the ruleset of the hosting country.

According to an article on [Sensei's Library](http://senseis.xmp.net/?Samsung2004Dispute), at least in 2004 the Samsung Cup used Korean rules.

The [Chunlan Cup](http://senseis.xmp.net/?ChunlanCup) is (again according to SL) the only international tournament played by Chinese rules.

The Ing Cup uses Ing rules.

I guess most other tournaments use Korean or Japanese (territory scoring) rules (?).